# Calculate road distances between points in QGIS 3.4?

Tags: qgis, point, distance

I would like to calculate road distances between a series of points. I don't have any road network layer, I need to rely on OpenStreetMap.

What is the best plugin available right now? And how should I organize the layer with points in order to calculate the road distances between them? I would like the outcome (distances) to be expressed in meters (I am working at the urban scale).

Comment: "Best" questions are problematic because they are inherently *opinion-based*. Even without "best" , you've got two questions here, violating the One question per Question policy.